# Empty summary error in terraform when runs in circleci

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, circleci, terragrunt

I'm using terraform and terragrunt to create some repositories in bitbucket, and since they do not have an official provider I'm using one from DrFaust92/bitbucket. I have done everything in my computer and I could apply all, now I'm moving the workflow to circle ci, and when I run it there I always get this error:

```
bitbucket_repository.repository: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Empty Summary: This is always a bug in the provider and should be reported 
  to the provider developers.
│ 
│   with bitbucket_repository.repository,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "bitbucket_repository" "repository":
│    5: resource "bitbucket_repository" "repository" {
```

The resource does not have anything in special:

```
resource "bitbucket_repository" "repository" {
  name        = var.name
  description = var.description
  owner       = var.owner
  project_key = var.project_key
  language    = var.project_language
  fork_policy = var.fork_policy
  is_private  = true
}
```

I'm using terraform 1.3.7 and terragrunt 0.43.1 (in my computer and in circle ci, both run with the same versions). It fails when it access any tfstate: if the tfstate already exists, it throws the error when planning, if it doesn't, the plan runs well, but when I apply it fails with the same error.

Any help to fix this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely issue associated with provider version. In your local, it may have a certain version downloaded/cached. Within Circle CI, it may be fetching latest provider that is available(which may have some issues). I would suggest you find the provider version currently in use locally, and then add required_providers block accordingly to make sure that it uses the same version of the provider. You can find the version presently in use from the terminal output that is generated on 'terraform init'. Below is the sample block to specify specific provider version(taken from: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aeirola/bitbucket/latest/docs/resources/repository).

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    bitbucket = {
      source  = "DrFaust92/bitbucket"
      version = "v2.30.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just realized that the source mentioned above is no longer maintained. You may want to use this source instead: https://github.com/DrFaust92/terraform-provider-bitbucket

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Locally I deleted everything to run it again and still works, but remotely doesn't. I have the required providers as you show (version should be 2.30.0 without the v)., using the last available.

Comment: Oh, then it would be better to report this issue in their repository: https://github.com/DrFaust92/terraform-provider-bitbucket/issues